# Problema al recojer una fecha con Spring form

Tags: java, date, spring-mvc, jstl

Tengo un JSP que crea una instancia, una propiedad del objeto es de tipo Date.
El problema surge cuando relleno el form y hago Submit, que me da  este error de "conversión" de String a Date:

```
ene 25, 2019 5:39:25 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerExceptionResolver logException
ADVERTENCIA: Resolved [org.springframework.validation.BindException: org.springframework.validation.BeanPropertyBindingResult: 1 errors
Field error in object 'jugador' on field 'fechaNacimiento': rejected value [2019-01-02]; codes [typeMismatch.jugador.fechaNacimiento,typeMismatch.fechaNacimiento,typeMismatch.java.util.Date,typeMismatch]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [jugador.fechaNacimiento,fechaNacimiento]; arguments []; default message [fechaNacimiento]]; default message [Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.util.Date' for property 'fechaNacimiento'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.util.Date' for property 'fechaNacimiento': no matching editors or conversion strategy found]]
```

así tengo la parte de este atributo en el formulario:

```
    <tr>
            <td>Fecha Nacimiento</td>
            <td><sf:input path="fechaNacimiento" type="date" /></td>
        </tr>
```

Comment: Puedes utilizar el DateTimeFormat @DateTimeFormat(iso=ISO.DATE)
Date fechaNacimiento; te dejo la documenación https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/format/annotation/DateTimeFormat.ISO.html

Comment: con la anotacion @DateTimeFormat ya había probado y sigue el mismo error

Comment: Tal vez esto sea de ayuda: http://javapro.org/blog/formatear-long-date-jsp/